# GTK+3 size-allocate event not real time like GTK+2

Tags: c, linux, gtk

I am trying to migrate from GTK+2 to GTK+3, and have found a problem. In GTK+2, the size-allocate event happens in real time as the window is actively resized by the user. But in GTK+3 the resize does not happen until the mouse click is released, there are no size-allocate signals while it is being dragged like in GTK+2. Is there any fix for that, or is that just how GTK+3 is? I can see that nothing in the window is updated until the mouse click drag is released, where in GTK+2 things in the window actively adjust.

I need the widgets updated as the window is actively resized, and to know in real time the size of all the widgets so some can be redrawn as the size is changed, as it is needed to see a pattern while resizing. But in GTK+3 the widgets don’t give any size changes or update until the drag event is done (mouse button is released after dragging the window to the desired size). This won’t work for me, and if there is no solution, I will be forced to stick with GTK+2.

Edit: I was asked to provide code that worked in GTK2, so here is a small program that works like needed in gtk2, where the height and width are shown as the window is resized, but in gtk3 the height and width are only shown after the mouse button is released when done resizing the window. I can also clearly see that in gtk3 that the inside area of the window is not resizing until the mouse button is released, so it seems that gtk3 itself is not resizing any widgets until it detects that the resize is done.

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
  main_window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(main_window), "test window");
  g_signal_connect(main_window, "size-allocate", G_CALLBACK(getsize_main_window), NULL);
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(main_window), 800, 600);
  gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(main_window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(main_window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
  gtk_widget_show_all(main_window);
  gtk_main();
  return 0;
}

void getsize_main_window(GtkWidget *widget, GtkAllocation *allocation, void *data)
{
  printf ("main window width = %d, height = %d\n", allocation->width, allocation->height);
}
```

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and post the [relevant] `gtk2` code in a code block here. And, what you have for an attempt at `gtk3` in a different code block. I suspect that `gtk3` _will_ let you do this, but you might have to have an additional configuration call to change the default behavior regarding when/how many resize events are sent.

Comment: I was afraid someone would ask for code. I have two very large programs with this issue, and it will take some time for me to be able to write a small program to replicate the issue. I was hoping for a more easy solution.

Comment: I added the line of code that works in gtk2 but not the same in gtk3. I hope that is enough for you.

Comment: I added a small sample program example.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded, built, and ran your test program built against both `gtk+-2.0` and `gtk+-3.0`. I'm using fedora 29 and have *both* `gtk2` and `gtk3` installed

The program behaved similarly for both versions. I get a similar event log and event frequency.

So, I am *unable* to reproduce your problem here.

Were you able to *verify* the "bad" behavior for your *test* program with `gtk3` on your system? That is, does it accurately demonstrate your issue as well as your full program? Are there any additional considerations not previously mentioned?

Before I ran this test, I *was* going to suggest that there *might* be a better signal/event to hook off of. And, that the behavior for `gtk2` might have been a side effect (that got "fixed" in `gtk3`). I *was* going to try different events to see if one was a better choice.

Note that I'd be glad to revisit the issue if you can improve your example code (i.e. until it "breaks" with `gtk3`).

---

Note that your example program didn't compile cleanly at first. So, I fixed the compilation errors.

I added some hires timestamping to your log messages to aid in the debug.

Here is the modified program (as `test.c`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

gpointer main_window;

typedef long long tsc_t;

int last_wid = -99999;
int last_hgt = -99999;
int evt_count = 0;
tsc_t tsczero;
tsc_t tsctlat;

tsc_t
tscget(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    tsc_t tsc;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&ts);

    tsc = ts.tv_sec;
    tsc *= 1000000000;
    tsc += ts.tv_nsec;

    tsc -= tsczero;

    return tsc;
}

double
tscsec(tsc_t tsc)
{
    double sec;

    sec = tsc;
    sec /= 1e9;

    return sec;
}

void
getsize_main_window(GtkWidget *widget, GtkAllocation *geo, void *data)
{
    int chgflg = 0;
    tsc_t tscnow;

    tscnow = tscget();

    if (last_wid != geo->width)
        chgflg = 1;

    if (last_hgt != geo->height)
        chgflg = 1;

    ++evt_count;

    if (chgflg) {
        printf("%.9f getsize_main_window: width=%d%+d height=%d%+d events=%d (ELAPSED: %.9f)\n",
            tscsec(tscnow),
            geo->width, geo->width - last_wid,
            geo->height, geo->height - last_hgt,
            evt_count,
            tscsec(tscnow - tsctlat));
        evt_count = 0;
    }

    if (chgflg) {
        last_wid = geo->width;
        last_hgt = geo->height;
    }

    tsctlat = tscnow;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buf[100];

    tsczero = tscget();
    tsctlat = tscget();

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    main_window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    sprintf(buf,"test window v%d",V);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(main_window), buf);

    g_signal_connect(main_window, "size-allocate",
         G_CALLBACK(getsize_main_window), NULL);

    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(main_window), 800, 600);
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(main_window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(main_window), "destroy",
        G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    gtk_widget_show_all(main_window);
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the [crude] `Makefile` that I created:

```
ifndef V
V := 2
endif

PKG = gtk+-$(V).0
CFLAGS += $(shell pkg-config --cflags $(PKG))
LIBS = $(shell pkg-config --libs $(PKG))

all: test

test.o: test.c
    cc -c $(CFLAGS) "-DV=$(V)" test.c

test: test.o
    cc -o test test.o $(LIBS)

clean:
    rm -f *.o test
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for taking the time to test the code, and to provide the insight that the issue was not repeatable for you. For me the code had the same issue as the original. So that made me look in a different direction, and I found my problem. It is the LXDE desktop environment. If I switch to XFCE it works like it is supposed to. There is a specific reason I want to use Lubuntu, so this is a setback for me. More work to do to figure out the best way to deal with this.

I am considering this to be solved, although not truly resolved.